# How to get User Input as NVL() functions alternate output in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, user-input, nvl

This query checks for all the employee under a given manager along with level,manager id,manager name. While running this the manager name column for **level 1** contains **null** which basically means they are directly under the inputted manager . How can i get the name of the inputted manager in manager name column for level 1.

I am using Oracle 11g.

```
    select id,(firstname||' '||lastname) as name,managerid, 
    nvl(prior (firstname||' '||lastname),'want user input shown here') as manager_name, level
    from employee
    connect by prior id = managerid
    start with managerid=(select id from employee where firstname = '&firstname' and 
    lastname='&lastname') order by level;
```

Comment: Hi. please edit the question and show sample table data and expected output.  thanks

Comment: When you say "user input", do you mean that you want to have the user input values by typing them in or something of that nature? Oracle SQL has no such ability. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the question tags and add further explanation of what you're trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis `&firstname` is the syntax for substitution variable in [SQL*Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Plus). A minor detail that the OP forgot to mention :-)

Comment: @Abra: thank you, I'm aware of that. I'm hoping that OP will tell us whether the "user input" to which he refers is the `&firstname` and `&lastname` substitution vars, or if he has something else in mind.

Comment: @BobJarvis I am sorry for the confusion. I meant &firstname & &lastname as the user input(substitution vars)

Answer (score 0):

I used the stock scott.emp table for my example, you should be able to modify it accordingly:

```sql
WITH starter AS (
  SELECT b.empno, b.ename 
  FROM scott.emp b
  WHERE b.ename = 'KING'
)
SELECT a.ename, 
       NVL(PRIOR(a.ename), (SELECT s.ename FROM starter s))
FROM scott.emp a
CONNECT BY a.mgr = PRIOR (a.empno)
START WITH a.mgr = (SELECT s.empno FROM starter s);
```

I admit, it is a bit of a kludge, but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

User inputted means the firstname and lastname which is substitution variable here.

You can use `&&` as shown below.

```
select id,(firstname||' '||lastname) as name,managerid, 
    nvl(prior (firstname||' '||lastname),'&&firstname &&lastname') as manager_name, level
    from employee
    connect by prior id = managerid
    start with managerid=(select id from employee where firstname = '&&firstname' and 
    lastname='&&lastname') order by level;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: @SwarnabChoudhury refer to [DEFINE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm#SQPUG037) in _SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference_

Comment: Yes, DEFINE will work but substitution will be a single sql.

Comment: I was just trying to point out to the OP that there is a difference between `&` and `&&` in _SQL*Plus_.

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.